# What KOMA-Script article (scrartcl) has that KOMA-Script book (scrbook) does not?

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, scrartcl, book-class

I'm trying to understand the difference between the KOMA-Script article class `scrartcl` and the  KOMA-Script book class `scrbook`?

As I understanding actually I can do every thing I can do with the article class also with the book class. But maybe I'm wrong.

So I was wondering: **What can I do using `scrartcl` that I can't do with `scrbook`?** Are there, i.e., options at  KOMA-Script's article class that the book class does not have?

Comment: The abstract  is the first thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: @Johannes_B, thank you! but there are more things? Or it's just this?

Comment: A KOMA-script article doesn't have chapters... And I guess there are more things. Also some options have different default settings, like a scrbook is two sided by default (but this can be changed). I'm unsure why you asked your question. If it was just out of curiosity, ok. But other ways, you should just ask yourself: Am I writing a book or an article or whatever. By this, most options are set "the right way". Btw. you can easily change the `documentclass` if you come to a point where you change your mind

Comment: A title with article is also relatively small on not on its own page (by default). One-side vs. twoside. Blank pages with books. There are also KOMA-reports.

Comment: @Johannes_B `scrbook` and `scrreprt` both do also provide `titlepage=false`. So this is one more default only.

Comment: The differences between `scrreprt`, `scrbook` and `scrartcl` are (mostly) marked by margin text `scrreprt`, `scrbook` or `scrartcl` in chapter 3 of the KOMA-Script manuals. They are similar to the differences of `book`, `report` and `article`.

Comment: @Ben, I asked it because I was curious... I play with both and I tried to understand the benefits of the article...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The KOMA-Script article class `scrartcl` is like the standard class `article` designed for (more or less short) articles. The KOMA-Script book class `scrbook` is like the standard class `book` designed for scientific books from about some dozen up to several thousand pages. The KOMA-Script report class `scrreprt` is like the standard `report` class somewhere between the article and the book class but more near to the book class. They differ from the book classes mostly in the defaults. And you can always use the book class with change of some defaults instead of the report class. So some persons say it is not really needed.

### Single-/Double-sided

Submission of articles often should be single-sided printed. So this is the default of `scrartcl` and `article`. But you can change it using option `twoside`.

Reports are a kind of paper often found in folders or discussed on round (or squared) tables. So they are also often printed as single-side documents. And so single-side layout/printing is the default of most report classes like `scrreprt` and `report` too.

Books are almost always double-sided. So this is the default of `scrbook` and `book`. But you can change it using option `twoside=false` (KOMA-Script only) or `oneside`.

### Document Titles

Usually articles do not use a complete page for the document title, but put the title on the top of the first page often followed by a short abstract as an eye catcher and sometimes followed by a table of contents. Not using a title page but a so called in-page title for titles made by `\maketitle` is also the default of `scrartcl` (and `article`). But you can change this default by option `titlepage`.

Books usually have several title pages (don't mix this with the cover!) as part of the book block. Usually books have a half-title. This is the first page of the block. It often does show only the main title of the book. The verso page of the half-title is either a blank page or the frontispiece. The next page is the main title page with title, author and several more elements. The verso page of the main title is often a kind of imprint with legal notes, edition, printer etc. The KOMA-Script `\maketitle` of `scrbook` does provide all these pages (and also a dedication page) by default. However you also can switch back to a in-page title using option `titlepage=false`.

The abstract of a book is generally a chapter (with or) without a number.

Providing or not providing a special `abstract` environment indeed has consequences for the available options. For example the KOMA-Script option `abstract` wouldn't make sense in `scrbook`. So only `scrartcl` and `scrreprt` provide this option.

### Parts, Chapter, Section …

Sometimes in books the titles pages, the preface, the table of contents and some other tables/lists are flagged by roman page numbers and not numbered chapters headings. Book classes therefore provide commands `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` (and `\backmatter`) to separate these parts. Even though the KOMA-Script author is not a fan of roman page numbers, `scrbook` also provides these commands.

Article do not have such a separation into front, main and back. So article classes usually do not provide commands for it. (And so are reports).

Usually articles do not have several parts. If they have parts a part heading is a heading like others too. It does not begin a new page nor have a page on its own. This is like `\part` in `scrartcl` (and `article`) work.

On the other side the parts of books are more or less independent and therefore a major break inside a book. Often parts have a kind of main title page with blank verso. This is like `\part` in `scrbook` (and `book`) work. But in KOMA-Script you can change this.

Usually articles do not have real chapters with a really eye-catching heading starting always on a new page. Therefore `scrartcl` and `article` do not provide `\chapter`.

Books do have real chapters. And to make them eye catchers, chapters always start on a new page, mostly on a new right/odd page. The heading is not aligned to the top of the page but starts after some white gap. The start page mostly do not have a head resp. a running head. This is `\chapter` in `scrbook` (and `book`). But in KOMA-Script it is only a default, that can be changed.

Sections of several levels (`\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`) and in-line headings (`\paragraph` and `\subparagraph`) are also supported by all three KOMA-Script (or standard) classes.

The difference in providing or not providing chapters has indeed consequences for the available options. For example option `open=right` (KOMA-Script only) or `openright` does not make sense for article classes.

### More

There are several more distinctions in the defaults of `scrartcl` and `scrbook`. But most of them can be easily changed by options or commands.

### Conclusion

Don't ask, what article classes have that book classes do not. Ask: What kind of document do I write? Is it more an article or more a book. The main characteristic is: Should my document have real chapters that start on a new page? If so → use `scrbook` (or `scrreprt`). If not → use `scrartcl`.

Private note: I often use `scrartcl` for memos or notes. For software design papers I've formerly used `scrreprt`, now replaced by `scrbook` with option `twoside=false`.